# How to resolve Object Object in state Message

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reduce

it's possible to know why i get Object Object in place of error Message in the state of reducer. I need to get
{error : "ce Message......"} in place of "object Object" in message

here the capture of the dubuger [image: debugger of my code]

action function to describe the action during the registration

```
function register(user) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request(user));
        userService.UserRegister(user)
            .then(
                user => {
                    dispatch(success());
                    history.push('/login');
                    dispatch(alertActions.success(user.data.toString()));
                }, error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
                }
            );
    };


    function request(user) {
        return {
            type: userConstants.REGISTER_REQUEST,
            user
        }
    }

    function success(user) {
        return {
            type: userConstants.REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            user
        }
    }

    function failure(error) {
        return {
            type: userConstants.REGISTER_FAILURE,
            error
        }
    }
}
```

my reducer

```
// reducer.js here
import { userConstants } from '../utils/constants';

export function authentication(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        loggingIn: true,
        user: action.user
      };
    case userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loggedIn: true,
        user: action.user
      };
    case userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return {};
    
    case userConstants.REGISTER_FAILURE:
        return {};
    case userConstants.LOGOUT:
      return {
        loggedIn: false,
        user: action.user
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: add your reducer and action functions

Comment: @Lemayzeur here some codes as asked thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

using JSON.stringify(object)

generally helps!

or use the object parameters like object.param!

Answer (score -1):

You are certainly dispatching an object instead of a string.
console.log your response and check it's shape